# Synchronise two Google accounts

Tags: youtube, google-calendar, google-plus, google, aol-mail

Since 1994 my primary email has been AOL (which I have grown to hate and want to delete). Years ago I set up an anonymous blog on Blogspot with a silly (dumb) Gmail address. Since then I have become a very very active user on:

- YouTube.
- Google Voice.
- Google Calendar.
- And even Google Plus.

All with my silly dumb email-address as the default (for I didn't have a choice).

Now I want to delete AOL, so I created a new Gmail address.

But how do I synchronise my accounts?

It won't let me change, or even add, a Gmail to my Google Voice etc.  So I can either be logged into everything / not email or visa versa.

P.S. I don't need to delete my silly email account. Especially since it gets thousands of emails daily from YouTube comments etc, that I would prefer to ignore. I'm not looking to forward these emails. But I cannot have this as my primary / main email.

Comment: Abusing the caps lock key is not going to endear you to many people.

Comment: what *exactly* are you trying to sync? It's not clear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic way to "synch" Google accounts to each other (and if there was, then you would get all the 1000s of emails that you want to escape from).   And as you've found, once you have a Google account that is named with a gmail address, you cannot change the email-address for that account.

You need to examine each Google service that you use adn decide what **data** from your old Google account you need to move to your new Google account.   Now, not all their services have a data-transfer service or work-around as yet.   (eg Picasa has one now, but didn't for a long time, Blogger has a procedure that you can follow to transfer a blog to a new account thou IMHO their documentation of it misses a few key elements).

The Google Takeout service might help with this - for example if you want to transfer some videos from the old to the new account, you could use Takeout to download them, then delete them from the old account an re-upload to the new account.

I've seen posts here from people asking about transferring Calendar contents.  Can't remember the answers though - but Google for it specifically and I'm sure you'll find the answer.

Google+ is a exception, because an individual person cannot have more than one profile.  So you effectively need to transfer your G+ identify from old to new accounts.  I'm sure there is a way to do this, but cannot remember at the moment.

Your contacts (used in gmail and Google-plus) is one area that you almost certainly need to transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to do the syncing manually.

- **Google Calendar**: do an export/import from your old to your new Google account.  This is very straightforward, there's a menu for that, to export to a Google or a standard file format.
- **Google Contacts**: same as with Calendar; export to file on old account, import from file on new account.
- **AOL mail to Gmail**: import all your e-mails from AOL into a local client, like Mozilla Thunderbird.  You can add you Gmail account to it using IMAP, and manually 'drag' your downloaded AOL e-mails into the appropriate Gmail folders.  Thunderbird will automatically sync (upload) those mails to your Gmail inbox online.  Several tools can be found to help you with this if you search online.
- **Google+**: Google released [a migration tool](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/how-to-migrate-a-google-profile-to-a-different-account.php) (Google Takeout) for this, but I haven't used that myself, so no guarantees.

Can't comment on **Google Voice**, as I do not use that service.  Might just be a question of stop using the 'silly' account, and switching over.